# Easiest way for USB-C to USB-A adapter design

Tags: usb, adapter

I'm looking through USB 3.1 specs and can't find any answer about one simple question.

I'm designing USB Type C to USB 3.0 Female A adapter, which will require USB 3.0 bandwidth (5Gbps) and standard 3.0 supply (900mA@5V). The idea i can't determine - can it be done without special ICs (like TUSB321 or CCG1/2)?

What i'm thinking for now: it can't be done without something like TUSB321 (which determines necessary current through CC). If i'm wrong - i'll be glad to hear it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wiring for what I believe you are describing is in the USB Type-C document, section 3.6.  Link to that document:
https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/USB%20Type-C%20Spec%20R2.0%20-%20August%202019.pdf

If that is not the wiring diagram you are looking for then it may be because you are thinking of a cable or adapter not allowed by the USB specifications.  The allowed cables and adapters are in section 2.2 of that document.

Comment: Thank you for your response! This question originates from 2015, and I'm afraid I do not even recall how this project ended. But now, I indeed know the correct answer - described adapter will require at least two ICs (or a single combined): configuration logic (the one which handles CCx pins) + high-speed mux (for supporting type c cable rotation)

Comment: Right, this is an old question.  I have a habit of not noticing the date.  I'm pleased to know someone found my answer helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Yes all you need in this case is a Rd( Pull down resistor) across CC line.

Comment: Some links to relevant specifications or example circuits would improve this answer.

Comment: You can refer USB Type-CTM Cable and Connector Specification Revision 1.1, April 3, 2015  from http://www.usb.org/developers/docs/usb_31_102015.zip

Also you can refer simplified gist of the specification and other details in http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B014SO7U4W

Answer (score 0):

USB C to USB A adapter at 5Gbps is quite simple. As described in page 77 of above document:

[image: connection diagram]

The USB C Host will drive the correct lane I guess.
[image: Example connection]

Source:[From Infenion site](https://community.infineon.com/t5/Knowledge-Base-Articles/Designing-Type-C-products-based-on-EZ-USB-FX3-and-CX3-KBA218460/ta-p/251806?_ga=2.4066994.322873545.1681651951-1558485158.1677248228)